# How do you filter out rows from a table

Tags: numbers

In a table with tens of thousands of records, I need to filter out all records where the first column of each record has "B" as value. I've tried activating "all filters but B", then select all, copy and paste in new a document, but the new document still includes all B records.

One solution could be to add a new numbered "index" column, then sorting all records by the first column and select and delete all the B's, and again reordering by the index column... But there just has to be a more efficient way...

Comment: If the data is sorted by another column (or you don't need to retain the order of the data) you can sort by the first column so you get all the B-values together and delete all of them. Then re-sort by the original column if you had one.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click inside the sheet => choose "Show Filter Options":

[image]

2. Choose which column the filter should be applied on:

[image]

3. Check which values you want to keep, and you'll see the data change at the same time:

[image]

4. Now you can just select the data, and copy/past to another sheet or to something else.

Comment: The goals was to get all filtered rows _out_ a table quickly. Sadly though, the table filter method doesn’t allow you to quickly select all filtered items… instead it tends to still select _everything_.

Comment: Humm - it is working fine for me - it is working the same way as in Microsoft Excel - select/unselect values and you get a new table view, which can be copied to any location inside or outside Numbers (or Excel) or that can be worked on.